# Property 'skin' is read only - > Flex Skinning

Tags: flex4, skin

I want to decorate a flex Button with a cutom skin component .

But when i point the 'skin' property to the source , it says "**Property skin is read only**"

My Button declaration :

```
<s:Button id="state"
    label="State View" 
    skin="CustomButtonSkin"            
    click="state_clickHandler(event)" />
```

This is inside a Component and CustomButtonSkin.mxml is in the same directory ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the **skinClass** property, not **skin**

Comment: oh , thank you .Also another way -- skin should be defined as  : skin="Components.CustomButtonSkin" . -- referring the package of th skin class .